# Refactor SqlDataReader neat api for doing database queries

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to refactor this shared sqlDataReader into a neat api for doing database queries? I convert the dictionary to sql parameters. Run the query and get the reader and then convert the rows to items. How can I convert this SqlParameter into a Dictionary<string, object> and then into a SqlParameter ?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            DB("Test");
        
    }
    
    public DB(string templateTitle){
        string queryName = "usp_Select_ByTitle";
            
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
                ["TemplateTitle"] = templateTitle
        };
        
        RunStoredProcedure(queryName, parameters, (reader) => {
            return new DB(reader);
        });
    }
    
    public DB(int? titleId, int? bookId){
        string queryName = "usp_Select_Byids";
            
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
                ["titleId"] = titleId,
                ["bookId"] = bookId,
        };
        
        RunStoredProcedure(queryName, parameters, (reader) => {
            return new DB(reader);
        });
    }
    
     public List<CompendiaNewDB> RunStoredProcedure(string queryName, IDictionary<string, object> parameters, Func<SqlDataReader> reader){
         var spParameters = new SqlParameter();
         string ConnectionString = "";
         string SQL = queryName;
         foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> p in parameters)
         {
                new SqlParameter("@" + p.Key, (p.Value.ToString().Length == 0) ? DBNull.Value : p.Value);
         }
         
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
         conn.Open();

         SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

         while (reader.Read())
         {

         }
         
     }
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I have this SqlParameter("@TemplateTitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar) but I want to use a Dictionary object?

Comment: How about you show us your *actual* code, rather than just uncompilable bits of it.

Comment: I updated the code hope it helps

Comment: [Not invented here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here). This is what libraries like [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) are for. Don't try to do it yourself. There's a lot of nuance you don't know about. Any complexity you still have when using Dapper is likely necessary and should be understood, not swept under the rug.

Comment: Just use one of existing ORMs instead of inventing one.

Comment: There is no other options is looks like a basic task?

Comment: @Jefferson it looks like it *should* be simple, but the raw ADO.NET API *isn't*. That's why libraries like Dapper (or at the more complex end: EF or LLBLGen) exist. For what you describe, Dapper is probably the ideal way of providing a simple API shape over the ADO.NET API. But trust me: what happens inside gets very non-simple very quickly. You don't want to redo all the work that those libraries do, and all the testing and optimization that has gone into them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Dapper, which exists literally to do this and only this:

```cs
public List<CompendiaNewDB> GetBooks(int? titleId, int? bookId)
{
    return connection.Query<CompendiaNewDB>(
        "usp_Select_Byids",
        new { titleId, bookId }, // named parameters/args
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
    ).AsList();
}
```

The library will know more about using ADO.NET correctly than most casual users will, and is pretty reliable and trusted.